# I need help figuring out a paint color in a picture

Tags: paint

[image]

I need professionals help please.

I am changing the paint job of my car. There is a color I love, I found a picture of on the internet. I sent to the paint-shop and they are finding it difficult to pinpoint what color it is.

I don't want them to go and use the wrong one. Please check the attached picture and help me figure out what color is it.

Thank you all in advance

Sadek

Comment: It's possible the picture has been edited with something like Photoshop and the color is not original or realistic.

Comment: Oh that will be a chock...

Comment: but I found something like:

VVIVID8 SATIN ALUMINUM SILVER MATTE

and

Matt Chrome Metallic Dark Gray

This might be it??

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like one of the Designo colours, most likely a Magno finish which is a semi-matte satin finish but with a pearl lustre.  You can see more about the Designo colours at this [link](https://www.mercedes-benz.co.uk/passengercars/mercedes-benz-cars/designo/designo-paint-upholstery.module.html)

You'll have to consult with your paint shop to ensure that they're able to source and apply this finish to your vehicle.

Comment: You are the man !! No you are the god... looks it is the "Designo Allanite Grey Magno"

Thank you dear!

Comment: So, they will need to be skilled and have good equipment, won't be doing that round behind the bike shed!